# Send SMS to mysql contact using php pdo

Tags: php, html

[These images are from my database table, When I click on Youth from the announcement page I want the message to be sent to only the phone of the youth in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25P9u.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMtWW.png)

Comment: Find SMS provider and use his API to send SMS.

Comment: One thing I know for sure - you can't send sms using php pdo

Comment: You really should delete the second image, since it contains private data of different persons!

Comment: The names are correct, but the email address and phone numbers are not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As several mentioned in comments above, you need do do this with PHP, as you tagged in your question already.

For some projects, I use [Plivo](https://developers.plivo.com/) which has API documentation for PHP [here](https://api-reference.plivo.com/latest/php/resources/message/send-a-message). I have no connection to this company other than being a (small) client and there are certainly others that might be better.

But ultimately, if you have selected the group 'Youth' and have a message 'There will be youth service tonight', you could (after subscribing to and configuring the API) query the database for the SMS numbers that are have `Fellowship = 'Youth'` like:

```
SELECT
    `Phone`
FROM
    Table
WHERE
    `Fellowship` = 'Youth';
```

Then create a delimited string of phone numbers and send it to the API. The details of your form, database and API connection would need to be considered when building your final solution.

The other option would be to send them via email, and use the SMS gateways, though this doesn't tend to have the 'true SMS' feel given that they come from email addresses. CodeTuts has a tutorial [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-send-text-messages-with-php--net-17693).

This should get you started, but ultimately, you will need PHP (or other server-side language of your choice) to handle this.